# NSDictionary value replacing instead of adding in Plist

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

hi i tried to add values(book id,page number,notes) from NSdictionary to Plist but each time the new value replacing the previous one?but i need  all values in plist my code for adding dictionary to plist is

```
NSString *bid=@"95";
NSString *pnum=@"12";
userNotes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[userNotes setValue:userNotesTextview.text forKey:@"notes"];
[userNotes setValue:bid forKey:@"bookid"];
[userNotes setValue:pnum forKey:@"pagenumber"];
userNotesView.hidden=YES;
_background.hidden = YES;
userNotesTextview.text=@"";
[self savingMetaData];
  NSMutableArray *notes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [notes addObject:userNotes];

  NSMutableDictionary *final=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernotes"];
  [final writeToFile:metaDataPath atomically:YES];
```

and my plist look like

[image]

how can i solve this problem

[image]

Comment: You are overriding the existing array with one value, you should overwrite the array. Append values in existing array then update to plist.

Comment: i dont knw how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch the existing array from the plist as below, but first make sure you have copied you plist to Documents directory or, to some writable folder as below

```
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath=[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"yourplist.plist"];
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: docPath];
NSError *error = nil;
if(!fileExists) 
{
    NSString *strSourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourplist" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:strSourcePath toPath:docPath error:&error];         

}

NSString *path = docPath;
NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *notes=[plistdictionary objectForKey:@"usernotes"];
if(notes==nil){ 
   notes=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
}
NSString *bid=@"95";
NSString *pnum=@"12";
userNotes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[userNotes setValue:userNotesTextview.text forKey:@"notes"];
[userNotes setValue:bid forKey:@"bookid"];
[userNotes setValue:pnum forKey:@"pagenumber"];
[notes addObject:userNotes];
```

then finally

```
NSMutableDictionary *final=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernotes"];
[final writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
```

Note: You cannot write anything in MainBundle, so better to copy your plist to Documents directory and use from there..

Comment: plistdictionar ?is it a new mutable dictionary?

Comment: Read the note, you need to copy your plist to Documents Directory first then use from there..Because currently you are working on MainBundle, and MainBundle is read-only.

Comment: please check the new plist image in question ..now the 2nd user note comes under the first one

Comment: there is some problm ..it not adding values its showing same previous values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26839/discussion-between-naveen-and-iphonic)

Answer (score 1):

because plist can store value with unique key only. if you try to save value with same key it will replace old one with new value. so always save new value with new key (eg. item0, item1, item3 etc.)

following line will store two usernote with key @"usernotes1" and @"usernotes2" respectively

```
[final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernotes1"];
[final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernotes2"];
```

Comment: you mean ,i have to check the count of final and set a nwe value count+1 inside the for loop write data to for loop with key @"usernote%d",i  ??

Comment: both are the feasible way depending on the situation you are storing your data.

Comment: [final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernote %d",i];  this shows error of two many methode calls

Answer (score 1):

Plist structure looks like this

[image]

You can create a UserNote model class.

```
#define kBookID @"bookid"
#define kPageNumber @"pageNumber"
#define kNotes @"notes"

@interface UserNote : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *bookID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *pageNumber;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *notes;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

+ (NSArray *)savedUserNotes;
- (void)save;

@end
```

Initialize

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.bookID = dictionary[kBookID];
        self.pageNumber = dictionary[kPageNumber];
        self.notes = dictionary[kNotes];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Find the document path of plist file in documents directory. If the plist file is not there create a new one and return the path.

```
+ (NSString *)userNotesDocumentPath
{
    NSString *documentsPath  = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserNotes.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath])
    {
        NSString *bundleResourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"UserNotes" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *userNotes = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:bundleResourcePath];
        [userNotes writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
    }

    return documentsPath;

}
```

Fetches all saved usernotes from plist file.

```
+ (NSArray *)savedUserNotes
{
    NSString *documentsPath = [self userNotesDocumentPath];
    NSArray *savedNotes = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:documentsPath];
    NSMutableArray *savedUserNotes = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in savedNotes) {
        UserNote *note = [[UserNote alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
        [savedUserNotes addObject:note];
    }

    return savedUserNotes;

}
```

Saves a usenote to plist

```
- (NSDictionary *)userNoteDictionary
{
    return @{kBookID:self.bookID,kPageNumber:self.pageNumber,kNotes:self.notes};
}

- (void)saveUserNotesToPlist:(NSArray *)userNotes
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableUserNotes = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (UserNote *note in userNotes) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [note userNoteDictionary];
        [mutableUserNotes addObject:dict];
    }
    NSString *documentsPath  = [UserNote userNotesDocumentPath];
    [mutableUserNotes writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Save

- (void)save
{
    NSMutableArray *savedNotes = [[UserNote savedUserNotes] mutableCopy];
    [savedNotes addObject:self];
    [self saveUserNotesToPlist:savedNotes];
}
```

In you viewController where user makes a note

```
- (IBAction)saveUserNoteButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    UserNote *note = [UserNote new];

    note.bookID = @"95";
    note.pageNumber = @"12";
    note.notes = self.userNotesTextview.text;

    [note save];
}
```

[Demo Source Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestPlistWriter.zip)

Comment: @Naveen Yes of course. I have included source code to my answer.

Comment: I thought it would be very self evident. You just need to make an instance of UserNote and add it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: i wana add some more value to plist using ur demo project how can entr my values???

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *docPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Usernotes.plist"];
      NSLog(@"%@",docPath);
      NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
      NSMutableArray *notes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      notes=[plistdictionary objectForKey:@"usernotes"];
      NSLog(@"notes1%@",notes);
      NSString *bid=@"95";

Comment: @Naveen I have edited my answer. You can open the plist from xcode and add them manually. But it would be easier if use an external text editor to form the initial seed data.

Comment: NSString *pnum=@"12";
    userNotes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [userNotes setValue:userNotesTextview.text forKey:@"notes"];
    [userNotes setValue:bid forKey:@"bookid"];
    [userNotes setValue:pnum forKey:@"pagenumber"];
    userNotesView.hidden=YES;
   _background.hidden = YES;
   userNotesTextview.text=@"";
      NSLog(@"usernotes%@",userNotes);
     
      [notes addObject:userNotes];
      NSLog(@"notes%@",notes);
    [final setValue:notes forKey:@"usernotes"];
    [final writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
      NSLog(@"f%@",final);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26841/discussion-between-naveen-and-anupdas)