# Why is my Plist loading from bundle rather than Document Library

Tags: ios, xcode

I am pretty new to working with Plists and IOS. I am trying to load a tableview of records, and I am trying to load the Tableview from my documents folder in the project. It used to load from the bundle and then I pointed to the documents folder. I removed the plist from my project, and kept it in the documents folder, but I received a copy error: So, please look over my code and give me some idea of how to load from the documents folder in my application. I ran it in debug and it still loading only the 5 records from the plist in the bundle, not the 7 records that reside in my documents folder. Just to note, after I load the initial screen of tableView records, I take the option "+" at the top to load a blank screen to load another record, this I am writing to the document folder and it works, now I want to display those changes on the Master. I also am not certain how to refresh the screen. I have read a bit about "ViewDidLoad", but I am not certain how to use this method. Thank you in advance.

Regards,

```
 NSLog(@"loading data");
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Accounts";
//    NSString *accountFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Accounts2" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts2.plist"];
    accounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    account = [accounts objectForKey:@"Account"];
    number = [accounts objectForKey:@"Number"];
    dueDay = [accounts objectForKey:@"DayDue"];
    minAmount = [accounts objectForKey:@"MinAmount"];
    balance = [accounts objectForKey:@"Balance"];

    NSLog(@"data loaded");
```

Comment: You have a plist in your app bundle and you are loading the data from it. Where did you save the data in plist to app document directory?

Comment: This is a kind of question that keeps coming back. You can refer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15607725/767730) and an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15608165/767730) to that. It is doing the same thing. Just the difference is that it saves "notes" instead of your "account".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am sure the question is asked a lot and for those of us who understand programming it is a little confusing that you read from one place and update another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First common things that without having `plist` in bundle how to copy them in to document directory.? so please keep your `plist` file it to Bundle then copy in to document directory like bellow code:-

```
BOOL success;
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlistName.plist"];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if (success) return;

NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"yourPlistName.plist"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy Plist. Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

and you can get this plist file using this bellow line of code:-

```
NSString *path = filePath;
NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

you can directly get plist file from Resource (NSBundle) like bellow code:-

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPlistName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```