# How to update an existing plist file with a new folder and files

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, plist

I am in the process of updating a drum machine app that requires new audio samples to be added via the plist "SoundCatalog.plist"

I have tried to edit by adding new files but that seems to want to create a new plist and by changing the data in the existing plist but that simply caused the build to be unsuccessful. I'm sure I am missing something fundamental and have searched the net for an answer for how to update this plist.

Can somebody help with a step by step of the best way to update this plist with new audio samples.

As an update I have solved this via trial and error. It was simply a case of adding a new folder containing the samples to the hierarchy and then setting up a new array in the plist file. I did this using plist editor pro which seemed a bit easier than the bundled Xcode plist editor

Many Thanks

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607725/nsdictionary-value-replacing-instead-of-adding-in-plist/15607793#15607793 . If it helps

Comment: Hi, read through the answer you gave but I can't seem to grasp how to translate that to my issue. I found it useful in the sense of each entry requiring a new key but I am still stuck